# python - map two lists of different types

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, map-function

I have two lists, one containing strings, the other containing  WebElements (selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement).

The lists have the same number of elements.

For every WebElement i want to use the .send_keys() method in order to put each element of the first list of strings in each textbox relative to the elements of list of WebElements (sorry for redundancy).

I'm trying to improve my python skills, so every hint is well accepted.

WebElements list:

```
[<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement at 0x7f3470a53b90>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement at 0x7f3470a53550>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement at 0x7f3470285b10>,
 <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement at 0x7f3470285090>]
```

the main idea is to fill the WebElements textboxes with the strings using .send_keys method

I tried with the map command and with generators but I don't know it they fit to this case

Comment: If I understood right, a list comprehension should work just fine. Something like `[ webelement.send_keys(s) for (webelement, s) in zip(webelement_list, string_list) ]`

Comment: @enx no i think . since he wan to use function of send_key() in webelemnts  with respective string.creating of list is unnecessary

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар Actually, you don't have to keep it at all :D

Comment: @enx i didn't precisely understand what do you mean

Comment: Which part? If you don't know about list comprehensions, check [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: I know, but I didn't understand what "u don't have to keep it all".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) to pair up your `WebElement` objects with the strings:

```
for welement, text in zip(webelements_list, text_list):
    welement.send_keys(text)
```